# Is it ok to "over tighten" laptop heat sink screws? Is it ok for one screw being slightly less tight than the others?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, heatsink, screws

I have the Acer Nitro 5 AN515-53.

I have a screw that is tightened but may not be tightened ALL the way since the head is stripped, and I don't want to get a new one until I have to open my laptop again to re-apply thermal paste.

As long as all the other screws are fully tightened, will one screw being slightly less tight have no repercussions in heat conductivity?

Is there also no chance of causing damage or making heat conductivity less effective in making screws too tight other than stripped screws and is completely fine?

Comment: I suggest you fix this.  It is not too likely this will be an issue, but the heat sink could possibly take a set that is not truly parallel and flat to the mating surface. I suggest removing the heat sink, cleaning it, re-applying a thin layer of thermal paste and then tighten it evenly. Normal mechanical engineering issue.  It is never OK to overtighten.

Comment: No; it’s not ok to over tighten a heatsink screw you can do damage the CPU die. Likewise, uneven pressure from the heatsink, could result weird performance issues, surrounding temperature; You should fix it

Comment: Thank you, maybe I should reword "overtighten" to "snuggly tightened so it no longer rotates" in that case it would better than to have a screw that has any possibility of becoming loose over the years?
I pickup my laptop a lot and use one hand to hold under it, and one hand to wipe the surface it's on. Is this unlikely to loosen the screws overtime and is fine?

Answer (score 1):

Overtightening a heatsink screw could strip the screw, crack the cpu, or damage the socket.

Uneven pressure on the cpu may cause an uneven gap between the cpu and the heat sink, causing one side of the cpu to overheat.

Of course, just because one screw can't be tightened all the way doesn't mean that the heatsink isn't properly seated.  It might be fine.  That is in part why there are springs on these things.

There is a range of tightness that will work.  Overtightening other screws to make up for the stripped one is probably a bad idea, as it is less likely to seat the heat sink evenly.

Comment: Thanks! I heard l laptops are more unlikely to crack dies from simply tightening the screws because of the reduced pressure they have compared to desktops, is this true? I've never heard anyone crack their die from just tightening laptops screws.

Comment: You can crack anything by overtightening.  You just didn't try hard enough.  :-P  Probably would have to crack the socket or mis-seat the cpu before you cracked the die.

Comment: Guess I'm too careful to even consider using that much elbow grease haha. As long as it doesn't turn anymore when I put considerable force I guess it's in the perfect spot then.

Comment: On a laptop heat sink, it possible for thermal paste re-form/distribute unevenly overtime or will it pretty much stay the same?
All my heatsink screws are tight but one might not be as tightened as the others since it's stripped and hard to turn, though the head is touching the heatsink.
Pressure changes won't affect thermal paste form/distribution if the heatsink just doesn't move? 
Overall thermal paste doesn't change form overtime and a single screw not being super tight doesn't affect that nor makes heat conductivity/how dry the paste gets or less efficient faster overtime?